# How to scale HTML content so that it fits phone width using Swift?

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview

**What's the gist of the issue?**

The backend is sending me some HTML and I'm showing it in the app using UIWebView. The problem is that most of the times the images have more width than the phone width and you need to scroll the UIWebView horizontally. I have tried using `scales pages to fit` property of UIScrollView but what happens is that the content becomes too small.

**What help do I need?**

I wanted to know if there is any way that the screen width can be taken into account and certain elements such as the tables, images, videos are scaled appropriately?

**What I have done so far?**

I have tried tinkering the HTML by myself in code by scaling the images, videos etc but there are countless such situations which I'm not sure could be taken care of using this approach.

Comment: send the responsive HTML

Answer (score 0):

**Add this Code :**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){

        webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled=false;
        ScreenWidth = webView.scrollView.contentSize.width 
        webView.sizeToFit()
        self.tblView.reloadData()

    }
```